# Dynamic database and SQL queries

Tags: java, content-management-system, workflow, dynamic-data

This is what i need to create.
I have a web site where the user can come and design an application form according to their need/requirement. Basically there is a HTML designer available in the website to perform this action. The user can drag and drop HTML components which in turn creates an application form in pure HTML. For example, for creating the "Personal Section" the user can drag & drop the label component and TextBox component and put the label text as "FirstName" and so on. I need to have a database created according to the form the one user has created. If he created the personal section with only FirstName and LastName the table created should have only those two cols. (ie, its up to the user to decide on col name at the time of form creation, the SQL queries for inserting and Updating DB fields all should perform dynamically). Please help me to solve this issue. Any suggested pattern there to apply? (The web application is created using Java)

Any help will be appreciated greatly

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to code for some sort of form builder which builds the form on the fly and can take help from following code to create dynamic sql tables. This is just a hint not the perfect solution for your problem

try {

```
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  

   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbctest", "root", "123");  
   Statement st = con.createStatement();  

   System.out.println("connection has been made ");  

   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  
   System.out.println("please enter table name ");  
   String tableName = scanner.next();  

   String strr = null;  

   System.out.println("Enter no of columns you like to use: ");  
   int noc = scanner.nextInt();  

   for (int i = 1; i <= noc; i++) {  
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(  
      System.in));  
    System.out.println("Enter column name with type ");  
    String s1 = bf.readLine();  
    if (strr == null) {  
     strr = s1;  

    } else {  
     strr = strr + s1;  

    }  

   }  

   st.executeUpdate("create table " + tableName + "(" + strr + ")");  
   System.out.println("your table " + tableName  
     + " has been created!!!");  

   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);  
   ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();  
   int NumOfCol = rsmd.getColumnCount();  
   System.out.println("Number of Columns of your table =" + tableName  
     + " " + NumOfCol);  
   System.out.println("Column names are ");  
   for (int i = 1; i <= NumOfCol; i++) {  
    System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(i));  
   }  
   String strn = null;  
   System.out.println("please enter values you need to insert");  

   for (int i = 1; i <= NumOfCol; i++) {  
    String s5 = scanner.next();  
    if (strn == null) {  
     strn = s5;  

    } else  
     strn = strn + s5;  

   }  
   System.out.println(strn);  

   st.executeUpdate("insert into " + tableName + " values" + "("  
     + strn + ")");  
   System.out.println("your table " + tableName  
     + " has been filled!!!");  

   con.close();  
   System.out.println("connection has been colsed ");  

  }  

  catch (Exception e) {  

   System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
  }
```

Comment: Here in my problem, the Db table col's are generated according to the type of form which is being designed by the user. He just drags and drops the HTML component to create a design.

Comment: Ya i got your point and that's why i am suggesting you to look for some sort of form builder tool which creates html web forms dynamically and stores the values posted from theses dynamic web forms into database.  You may found following link  useful https://code.google.com/p/jquery-form-builder-plugin/